# Project Euler #11 Largest Product in a Grid | Cache-optimized + sliding window (C++14)

Tags: c++, performance, object-oriented, programming-challenge, c++14

Source: *HackerRank & ProjectEuler.net*

**Problem: Largest Product in a Grid**
In the 20×20 grid below, four numbers along a diagonal line have been marked in red.

```
08 02 22 97 38 15 00 40 00 75 04 05 07 78 52 12 50 77 91 08
49 49 99 40 17 81 18 57 60 87 17 40 98 43 69 48 04 56 62 00
81 49 31 73 55 79 14 29 93 71 40 67 53 88 30 03 49 13 36 65
52 70 95 23 04 60 11 42 69 24 68 56 01 32 56 71 37 02 36 91
22 31 16 71 51 67 63 89 41 92 36 54 22 40 40 28 66 33 13 80
24 47 32 60 99 03 45 02 44 75 33 53 78 36 84 20 35 17 12 50
32 98 81 28 64 23 67 10(26)38 40 67 59 54 70 66 18 38 64 70
67 26 20 68 02 62 12 20 95(63)94 39 63 08 40 91 66 49 94 21
24 55 58 05 66 73 99 26 97 17(78)78 96 83 14 88 34 89 63 72
21 36 23 09 75 00 76 44 20 45 35(14)00 61 33 97 34 31 33 95
78 17 53 28 22 75 31 67 15 94 03 80 04 62 16 14 09 53 56 92
16 39 05 42 96 35 31 47 55 58 88 24 00 17 54 24 36 29 85 57
86 56 00 48 35 71 89 07 05 44 44 37 44 60 21 58 51 54 17 58
19 80 81 68 05 94 47 69 28 73 92 13 86 52 17 77 04 89 55 40
04 52 08 83 97 35 99 16 07 97 57 32 16 26 26 79 33 27 98 66
88 36 68 87 57 62 20 72 03 46 33 67 46 55 12 32 63 93 53 69
04 42 16 73 38 25 39 11 24 94 72 18 08 46 29 32 40 62 76 36
20 69 36 41 72 30 23 88 34 62 99 69 82 67 59 85 74 04 36 16
20 73 35 29 78 31 90 01 74 31 49 71 48 86 81 16 23 57 05 54
01 70 54 71 83 51 54 69 16 92 33 48 61 43 52 01 89 19 67 48
```

The product of these numbers is 26 × 63 × 78 × 14 = 1788696.

What is the greatest product of four adjacent numbers in the same direction (up, down, left, right, or diagonally) in the 20×20 grid?

**Input**
Input consists of 20 lines each containing 20 integers.

**Output**
Print the required answer.

**Limits**
0 ≤ each integer in the grid ≤ 100

**Sample**
Input

```
89 90 95 97 38 15 00 40 00 75 04 05 07 78 52 12 50 77 91 08  
49 49 99 40 17 81 18 57 60 87 17 40 98 43 69 48 04 56 62 00  
81 49 31 73 55 79 14 29 93 71 40 67 53 88 30 03 49 13 36 65  
52 70 95 23 04 60 11 42 69 24 68 56 01 32 56 71 37 02 36 91  
22 31 16 71 51 67 63 89 41 92 36 54 22 40 40 28 66 33 13 80  
24 47 32 60 99 03 45 02 44 75 33 53 78 36 84 20 35 17 12 50  
32 98 81 28 64 23 67 10 26 38 40 67 59 54 70 66 18 38 64 70  
67 26 20 68 02 62 12 20 95 63 94 39 63 08 40 91 66 49 94 21  
24 55 58 05 66 73 99 26 97 17 78 78 96 83 14 88 34 89 63 72  
21 36 23 09 75 00 76 44 20 45 35 14 00 61 33 97 34 31 33 95  
78 17 53 28 22 75 31 67 15 94 03 80 04 62 16 14 09 53 56 92  
16 39 05 42 96 35 31 47 55 58 88 24 00 17 54 24 36 29 85 57  
86 56 00 48 35 71 89 07 05 44 44 37 44 60 21 58 51 54 17 58  
19 80 81 68 05 94 47 69 28 73 92 13 86 52 17 77 04 89 55 40  
04 52 08 83 97 35 99 16 07 97 57 32 16 26 26 79 33 27 98 66  
88 36 68 87 57 62 20 72 03 46 33 67 46 55 12 32 63 93 53 69  
04 42 16 73 38 25 39 11 24 94 72 18 08 46 29 32 40 62 76 36  
20 69 36 41 72 30 23 88 34 62 99 69 82 67 59 85 74 04 36 16  
20 73 35 29 78 31 90 01 74 31 49 71 48 86 81 16 23 57 05 54  
01 70 54 71 83 51 54 69 16 92 33 48 61 43 52 01 89 19 67 48
```

Output

```
73812150
```

**My solution (C++14)**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <numeric>

// 2D grid represented by 1D vector for cache optimization
auto getGrid(int rows, int columns) {
    auto values = rows * columns;
    std::vector<int> grid(values);
    std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin), values, grid.begin());
    return grid;
}

class LargestProductInAGrid {
public:
    LargestProductInAGrid(std::vector<int> &grid, int rows, int columns, int nAdjacents) : grid_(grid), rows_(rows),
                                                                                           columns_(columns),
                                                                                           nAdjacents_(nAdjacents) {}

    auto largestProductInAGrid() {
        long long largestProduct = 0;

        for (auto row = 0; row < rows_; row++) {
            largestProduct = std::max(largestProduct, largestProductInARow(row));
        }

        for (auto column = 0; column < columns_; column++) {
            largestProduct = std::max(largestProduct, largestProductInAColumn(column));
            largestProduct = std::max(largestProduct, largestProductInARightDiagonal(column));
            largestProduct = std::max(largestProduct, largestProductInALeftDiagonal(column));
        }

        return largestProduct;
    }

private:
    long long largestProductInARow(int row) {
        int low = row * columns_, end = low + columns_;
        long long currentProduct = 0, highestProduct = 0;

        while (low + nAdjacents_ - 1 < end) {
            if (currentProduct == 0) {
                currentProduct = std::accumulate(grid_.begin() + low, grid_.begin() + low + nAdjacents_, 1LL,
                                                 std::multiplies<>());
            } else {
                currentProduct /= grid_[low - 1];
                currentProduct *= grid_[low + nAdjacents_ - 1];
            }

            if (currentProduct == 0) {
                auto zero = std::find(grid_.begin() + low, grid_.begin() + low + nAdjacents_, 0);
                low += zero - (grid_.begin() + low) + 1;
            } else {
                low++;
            }

            highestProduct = std::max(highestProduct, currentProduct);
        }

        return highestProduct;
    }

    int oneDIndex(int row, int column) {
        return row * columns_ + column;
    }

    long long largestProductInAColumn(int column) {
        int row = 0;
        long long currentProduct = 0, highestProduct = 0;

        while (row + nAdjacents_ - 1 < rows_) {
            if (currentProduct == 0) {
                currentProduct = 1;
                for (int i = row; i < row + nAdjacents_; i++) {
                    currentProduct *= grid_[oneDIndex(i, column)];
                }
            } else {
                currentProduct /= grid_[oneDIndex(row - 1, column)];
                currentProduct *= grid_[oneDIndex(row + nAdjacents_ - 1, column)];
            }

            if (currentProduct == 0) {
                while (grid_[oneDIndex(row, column)] != 0) {
                    row++;
                }
            }

            row++;

            highestProduct = std::max(highestProduct, currentProduct);
        }

        return highestProduct;
    }

    long long largestProductInARightDiagonal(int startingColumn) {
        int row = 0, column = startingColumn;
        long long currentProduct = 0, highestProduct = 0;

        while (row + nAdjacents_ - 1 < rows_ && column + nAdjacents_ - 1 < columns_) {
            if (currentProduct == 0) {
                currentProduct = 1;
                for (int i = row; i < row + nAdjacents_; i++) {
                    currentProduct *= grid_[oneDIndex(i, column + i)];
                }
            } else {
                currentProduct /= grid_[oneDIndex(row - 1, column - 1)];
                currentProduct *= grid_[oneDIndex(row + nAdjacents_ - 1, column + nAdjacents_ - 1)];
            }

            if (currentProduct == 0) {
                while (grid_[oneDIndex(row, column)] != 0) {
                    row++, column++;
                }
            }

            row++, column++;

            highestProduct = std::max(highestProduct, currentProduct);
        }

        return highestProduct;
    }

    long long largestProductInALeftDiagonal(int startingColumn) {
        int row = 0, column = startingColumn;
        long long currentProduct = 0, highestProduct = 0;

        while (row + nAdjacents_ - 1 < rows_ && column - nAdjacents_ + 1 >= 0) {
            if (currentProduct == 0) {
                currentProduct = 1;
                for (int i = row; i < row + nAdjacents_; i++) {
                    currentProduct *= grid_[oneDIndex(i, column - i)];
                }
            } else {
                currentProduct /= grid_[oneDIndex(row - 1, column + 1)];
                currentProduct *= grid_[oneDIndex(row + nAdjacents_ - 1, column - nAdjacents_ + 1)];
            }

            if (currentProduct == 0) {
                while (grid_[oneDIndex(row, column)] != 0) {
                    row++, column--;
                }
            }

            row++, column--;

            highestProduct = std::max(highestProduct, currentProduct);
        }

        return highestProduct;
    }

    std::vector<int> grid_;
    int rows_;
    int columns_;
    int nAdjacents_;
};

int main() {
    const int rows = 20, columns = 20, nAdjacents = 4;
    auto grid = getGrid(rows, columns);
    LargestProductInAGrid solution(grid, rows, columns, nAdjacents);
    std::cout << solution.largestProductInAGrid() << std::endl;
}
```

**Analysis**
Time complexity: \$O(r * c)\$
Space complexity: \$O(1)\$, not counting initial data

**Comments**
In the past, I solved this problem when I was learning to program using the brute force method. This time, I wanted to optimize it for performance while maintaining a reasonable standard of readability.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. I have rolled back your last edit. Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `long long` for your products.  The maximum possible product of 4 numbers between 0 & 100 is \$100^4\$, which fits in 27 bits.  Using a `long` would be sufficient, as well as probably faster.

---

When traversing rows, columns, right diagonals and left diagonals, your `oneDIndex()` increases by 1, 20, 21, and 19, respectively.  The structure of your product_line maximum search is roughly the same in all 4 cases.  You could combine these functions into one general purpose utility function to handle all of the 4 cases, with appropriate parametrization of the starting points, stopping points and strides.

(Since this is a programming challenge, I will leave the realization of the above algorithm to the reader.)

Comment: Probably could template the largestProduct's type. My thinking was that 5+ elements would overflow with a long.

Comment: I implemented your suggestions here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/216426/follow-up-project-euler-11-largest-product-in-a-grid-cache-optimized-slid

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot more duplication here than I'd expect.  The processing of rows, columns, forward diagonals and reverse diagonals are all very similar to each other, particularly once the coordinates are linearised to an index into `grid`:

- rows have a step of 1 from one element to the next
- columns have a step of `columns` (or, in general, the "stride" of the array)
- diagonals have a step of `columns ± 1` depending on their direction.

The other difference is the start and end margins to prevent advancing beyond the 2D bounds of the array; these are easily adjusted according to the direction.

---

We ought to be more robust when reading inputs in `getGrid()`.  We could test `std::cin` after reading from it, or simply set it before reading to throw exceptions on failures.

Comment: I implemented your suggestions here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/216426/follow-up-project-euler-11-largest-product-in-a-grid-cache-optimized-slid