# (Follow-up) Project Euler #11 Largest Product in a Grid | Cache-optimized + sliding window (C++14)

Tags: c++, performance, object-oriented, programming-challenge, c++14

**Original code review:** [Project Euler #11 Largest Product in a Grid | Cache-optimized + sliding window (C++14)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/216386/project-euler-11-largest-product-in-a-grid-cache-optimized-sliding-window)

---

Source: *HackerRank & ProjectEuler.net*

**Problem: Largest Product in a Grid**
In the 20×20 grid below, four numbers along a diagonal line have been marked in red.

```
08 02 22 97 38 15 00 40 00 75 04 05 07 78 52 12 50 77 91 08
49 49 99 40 17 81 18 57 60 87 17 40 98 43 69 48 04 56 62 00
81 49 31 73 55 79 14 29 93 71 40 67 53 88 30 03 49 13 36 65
52 70 95 23 04 60 11 42 69 24 68 56 01 32 56 71 37 02 36 91
22 31 16 71 51 67 63 89 41 92 36 54 22 40 40 28 66 33 13 80
24 47 32 60 99 03 45 02 44 75 33 53 78 36 84 20 35 17 12 50
32 98 81 28 64 23 67 10(26)38 40 67 59 54 70 66 18 38 64 70
67 26 20 68 02 62 12 20 95(63)94 39 63 08 40 91 66 49 94 21
24 55 58 05 66 73 99 26 97 17(78)78 96 83 14 88 34 89 63 72
21 36 23 09 75 00 76 44 20 45 35(14)00 61 33 97 34 31 33 95
78 17 53 28 22 75 31 67 15 94 03 80 04 62 16 14 09 53 56 92
16 39 05 42 96 35 31 47 55 58 88 24 00 17 54 24 36 29 85 57
86 56 00 48 35 71 89 07 05 44 44 37 44 60 21 58 51 54 17 58
19 80 81 68 05 94 47 69 28 73 92 13 86 52 17 77 04 89 55 40
04 52 08 83 97 35 99 16 07 97 57 32 16 26 26 79 33 27 98 66
88 36 68 87 57 62 20 72 03 46 33 67 46 55 12 32 63 93 53 69
04 42 16 73 38 25 39 11 24 94 72 18 08 46 29 32 40 62 76 36
20 69 36 41 72 30 23 88 34 62 99 69 82 67 59 85 74 04 36 16
20 73 35 29 78 31 90 01 74 31 49 71 48 86 81 16 23 57 05 54
01 70 54 71 83 51 54 69 16 92 33 48 61 43 52 01 89 19 67 48
```

The product of these numbers is 26 × 63 × 78 × 14 = 1788696.

What is the greatest product of four adjacent numbers in the same direction (up, down, left, right, or diagonally) in the 20×20 grid?

**Input**
Input consists of 20 lines each containing 20 integers.

**Output**
Print the required answer.

**Limits**
0 ≤ each integer in the grid ≤ 100

**Sample**
Input

```
89 90 95 97 38 15 00 40 00 75 04 05 07 78 52 12 50 77 91 08  
49 49 99 40 17 81 18 57 60 87 17 40 98 43 69 48 04 56 62 00  
81 49 31 73 55 79 14 29 93 71 40 67 53 88 30 03 49 13 36 65  
52 70 95 23 04 60 11 42 69 24 68 56 01 32 56 71 37 02 36 91  
22 31 16 71 51 67 63 89 41 92 36 54 22 40 40 28 66 33 13 80  
24 47 32 60 99 03 45 02 44 75 33 53 78 36 84 20 35 17 12 50  
32 98 81 28 64 23 67 10 26 38 40 67 59 54 70 66 18 38 64 70  
67 26 20 68 02 62 12 20 95 63 94 39 63 08 40 91 66 49 94 21  
24 55 58 05 66 73 99 26 97 17 78 78 96 83 14 88 34 89 63 72  
21 36 23 09 75 00 76 44 20 45 35 14 00 61 33 97 34 31 33 95  
78 17 53 28 22 75 31 67 15 94 03 80 04 62 16 14 09 53 56 92  
16 39 05 42 96 35 31 47 55 58 88 24 00 17 54 24 36 29 85 57  
86 56 00 48 35 71 89 07 05 44 44 37 44 60 21 58 51 54 17 58  
19 80 81 68 05 94 47 69 28 73 92 13 86 52 17 77 04 89 55 40  
04 52 08 83 97 35 99 16 07 97 57 32 16 26 26 79 33 27 98 66  
88 36 68 87 57 62 20 72 03 46 33 67 46 55 12 32 63 93 53 69  
04 42 16 73 38 25 39 11 24 94 72 18 08 46 29 32 40 62 76 36  
20 69 36 41 72 30 23 88 34 62 99 69 82 67 59 85 74 04 36 16  
20 73 35 29 78 31 90 01 74 31 49 71 48 86 81 16 23 57 05 54  
01 70 54 71 83 51 54 69 16 92 33 48 61 43 52 01 89 19 67 48
```

Output

```
73812150
```

**My updated solution (C++14)**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

// 2D grid represented by 1D vector for cache optimization
auto getGrid(int rows, int columns) {
    auto values = rows * columns;
    std::vector<int> grid(values);
    std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin), values, grid.begin());

    if (std::cin.fail()) {
        throw std::runtime_error(
                "The input is invalid! Check the rows and columns in your input and that all numbers in the grid are integers between 0 and 100.");
    }
    return grid;
}

class LargestProductInAGrid {
public:
    LargestProductInAGrid(std::vector<int> &grid, int rows, int columns, int nAdjacents) : grid_(grid), rows_(rows),
                                                                                           columns_(columns),
                                                                                           nAdjacents_(nAdjacents) {}

    template<typename T>
    auto largestProductInAGrid() {
        T largestProduct = 0;

        for (auto row = 0; row < rows_; row++) {
            largestProduct = std::max(largestProduct,
                                      largestProductInASeries<T>(SeriesType::HORIZONTAL, row * columns_));
        }

        for (auto column = 0; column < columns_; column++) {
            largestProduct = std::max(largestProduct, largestProductInASeries<T>(SeriesType::VERTICAL, column));
            largestProduct = std::max(largestProduct, largestProductInASeries<T>(SeriesType::DIAGONAL_RIGHT, column));
            largestProduct = std::max(largestProduct, largestProductInASeries<T>(SeriesType::DIAGONAL_LEFT, column));
        }

        return largestProduct;
    }

private:
    enum SeriesType {
        HORIZONTAL, VERTICAL, DIAGONAL_RIGHT, DIAGONAL_LEFT
    };

    template<typename T>
    T largestProductInASeries(SeriesType type, int startingIndex) {
        int low = startingIndex, current = low;

        T currentProduct = initializeProductInASeries<T>(type, current);
        if (current < 0) return 0;
        T highestProduct = currentProduct;

        while (current >= 0) {
            if (currentProduct == 0) {
                while (grid_[low] != 0) low = nextIndex(type, low);
                low = nextIndex(type, low);
                current = low;
                currentProduct = initializeProductInASeries<T>(type, current);
            } else {
                currentProduct /= grid_[low];
                currentProduct *= grid_[current];

                low = nextIndex(type, low);
                current = nextIndex(type, current);
            }

            highestProduct = std::max(highestProduct, currentProduct);
        }

        return highestProduct;
    }

    template<typename T>
    T initializeProductInASeries(SeriesType type, int &index) {
        T product = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < nAdjacents_ && product > 0; i++) {
            product *= grid_[index];
            index = nextIndex(type, index);
            if (index < 0) return 0;
        }
        return product;
    }

    int nextIndex(SeriesType type, int currentIndex) {

        auto canAdvanceRight = bool((currentIndex + 1) % columns_);
        if (type == SeriesType::HORIZONTAL && canAdvanceRight) {
            return currentIndex + 1;
        }

        auto canAdvanceDown = currentIndex / columns_ + 1 < rows_;
        if (type == SeriesType::VERTICAL && canAdvanceDown) {
            return currentIndex + columns_;
        }

        if (type == SeriesType::DIAGONAL_RIGHT && canAdvanceRight && canAdvanceDown) {
            return currentIndex + columns_ + 1;
        }

        auto canAdvanceLeft = bool(currentIndex % columns_);
        if (type == SeriesType::DIAGONAL_LEFT && canAdvanceLeft && canAdvanceDown) {
            return currentIndex + columns_ - 1;
        }

        return -1;
    }

    std::vector<int> grid_;
    int rows_;
    int columns_;
    int nAdjacents_;
};

int main() {
    const int rows = 20, columns = 20, nAdjacents = 4;
    auto grid = getGrid(rows, columns);
    LargestProductInAGrid solution(grid, rows, columns, nAdjacents);
    std::cout << solution.largestProductInAGrid<int>() << std::endl;
}
```

**Analysis**
Time complexity: \$O(r * c)\$
Space complexity: \$O(1)\$, not counting initial data

**Comments**
Changes:

1. Combined the logic of rows, columns, and diagonals into a single method.
2. Templated the methods so that it can handle adjacent numbers <4 efficiently with `int` and between 5 and 9 numbers with `unsigned long long`.
3. getGrid now throws an exception when the input is invalid.

Answer (score 6):

I'd separate the concerns of storage (`Grid`) and the search (`longestProduct`), like this:

```
class Grid
{
    std::vector<int> grid;
    int rows;
    int columns;

public:
    Grid(int rows, int columns)
        : grid(rows * columns),
          rows(rows), columns(columns)
    {
    }

    void read(std::istream& in);
    long largestProduct(unsigned nAdjacents) const;
}
```

See how we can now re-use one grid and find its largest 3-product, 4-product, etc. without needed to re-instantiate.

To calculate a *n*-product, we just need to know the starting point, stride, and length:

```
private:
    long product(int x, int y, int step, unsigned n) const
    {
        long product = 1;
        for (auto *p = grid.data() + columns * x + y;  n-- > 0;  p += step) {
            product *= *p;
        }
        return product;
    }
```

We can create a "high water mark" type to save typing all those `std::max()` invocations:

```
// a simple value that can only be ovewritten by greater values
template<typename T>
struct MaxValue
{
    T value;

    MaxValue(T value = T{})
        : value(value)
    {}

    operator T() const
    {
        return value;
    }

    MaxValue& operator=(T other)
    {
        if (value < other)
            value = other;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Then our `largestProduct` search becomes much simpler (C++17, for my convenience):

```
long largestProduct(unsigned nAdjacents) const
{
    static const std::initializer_list<std::pair<int,int>> directions
        = {{0,1}, {1,1}, {1,0}, {1,-1}};

    MaxValue<long> largestProduct = 0;
    for (auto const [dy, dx]: directions) {
        // determine range to search
        auto const row_0 = 0u;
        auto const row_n = dy > 0 ? rows - nAdjacents : rows;
        auto const col_0 = dx < 0 ? nAdjacents : 0;
        auto const col_n = dx > 0 ? columns - nAdjacents : columns;
        auto const step = dy * columns + dx;
        // do the search
        for (auto r = row_0;  r < row_n;  ++r) {
            for (auto c = col_0;  c < col_n;  ++c) {
                largestProduct = product(r, c, step, nAdjacents);
            }
        }
    }
    return largestProduct;
}
```

---

## Full code

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iterator>
#include <istream>
#include <vector>

// a simple value that can only be ovewritten by greater values
template<typename T>
struct MaxValue
{
    T value;

    MaxValue(T value = T{})
        : value(value)
    {}

    operator T() const
    {
        return value;
    }

    MaxValue& operator=(T other)
    {
        if (value < other)
            value = other;
        return *this;
    }
};


class Grid
{
    std::vector<int> grid;
    int rows;
    int columns;

public:
    Grid(int rows, int columns)
        : grid(rows * columns),
          rows(rows), columns(columns)
    {
    }

    void read(std::istream& in)
    {
        // temporarily set in to throw on error
        auto saved_exceptions = in.exceptions();
        in.exceptions(std::ios_base::failbit | std::ios_base::badbit);

        auto values = rows * columns;
        std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<int>(in), values, grid.begin());

        // restore exception state
        in.exceptions(saved_exceptions);
    }

    long largestProduct(unsigned nAdjacents) const
    {
        static const std::initializer_list<std::pair<int,int>> directions
            = {{0,1}, {1,1}, {1,0}, {1,-1}};

        MaxValue<long> largestProduct = 0;
        for (auto const [dy, dx]: directions) {
            // determine range to search
            auto const row_0 = 0u;
            auto const row_n = dy > 0 ? rows - nAdjacents : rows;
            auto const col_0 = dx < 0 ? nAdjacents : 0;
            auto const col_n = dx > 0 ? columns - nAdjacents : columns;
            auto const step = dy * columns + dx;
            // do the search
            for (auto r = row_0;  r < row_n;  ++r) {
                for (auto c = col_0;  c < col_n;  ++c) {
                    largestProduct = product(r, c, step, nAdjacents);
                }
            }
        }
        return largestProduct;
    }

private:
    long product(int x, int y, int step, unsigned n) const
    {
        long product = 1;
        for (auto *p = grid.data() + columns * x + y;  n-- > 0;  p += step) {
            product *= *p;
        }
        return product;
    }
};



#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::istringstream in(R"(
89 90 95 97 38 15 00 40 00 75 04 05 07 78 52 12 50 77 91 08
49 49 99 40 17 81 18 57 60 87 17 40 98 43 69 48 04 56 62 00
81 49 31 73 55 79 14 29 93 71 40 67 53 88 30 03 49 13 36 65
52 70 95 23 04 60 11 42 69 24 68 56 01 32 56 71 37 02 36 91
22 31 16 71 51 67 63 89 41 92 36 54 22 40 40 28 66 33 13 80
24 47 32 60 99 03 45 02 44 75 33 53 78 36 84 20 35 17 12 50
32 98 81 28 64 23 67 10 26 38 40 67 59 54 70 66 18 38 64 70
67 26 20 68 02 62 12 20 95 63 94 39 63 08 40 91 66 49 94 21
24 55 58 05 66 73 99 26 97 17 78 78 96 83 14 88 34 89 63 72
21 36 23 09 75 00 76 44 20 45 35 14 00 61 33 97 34 31 33 95
78 17 53 28 22 75 31 67 15 94 03 80 04 62 16 14 09 53 56 92
16 39 05 42 96 35 31 47 55 58 88 24 00 17 54 24 36 29 85 57
86 56 00 48 35 71 89 07 05 44 44 37 44 60 21 58 51 54 17 58
19 80 81 68 05 94 47 69 28 73 92 13 86 52 17 77 04 89 55 40
04 52 08 83 97 35 99 16 07 97 57 32 16 26 26 79 33 27 98 66
88 36 68 87 57 62 20 72 03 46 33 67 46 55 12 32 63 93 53 69
04 42 16 73 38 25 39 11 24 94 72 18 08 46 29 32 40 62 76 36
20 69 36 41 72 30 23 88 34 62 99 69 82 67 59 85 74 04 36 16
20 73 35 29 78 31 90 01 74 31 49 71 48 86 81 16 23 57 05 54
01 70 54 71 83 51 54 69 16 92 33 48 61 43 52 01 89 19 67 48
)");
    Grid grid{20, 20};
    grid.read(in);

    std::cout << grid.largestProduct(4) << std::endl;
}
```

---

From here, we might investigate ideas like the rolling product; that might provide less benefit than you expect, given how much more expensive division is compared to multiplication.

Comment: I don't agree with the design to tightly couple the reading of the data and the function largestProduct. What if the data comes from a database, a web response, a file, a POST request, etc.? Technically we could transform into a string then pass it an an istream, but we could do better. In fact, largeProduct is a pure function, and it doesn't need to instantiate an object. I implemented in a class because I didn't want to pass 6 parameters to helper functions.

Comment: I think the best design would be to have a Grid struct that can be constructed by the different classes that would implement different ways to get the data, and then pass that Grid struct + nAdjacents to a pure function largestProduct as parameters.

Comment: The class LargestProductInAGrid is like a closure, and all you have to do is add a setter to be able to change the grid or number of adjacent products.

Comment: "*a Grid struct that can be constructed by the different classes...*" - Indeed, I agree with that.  I was just being lazy when I made `read()` a member.